# Jquery functions and infinite scroll elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I have a script that popup a window for every link with class attached

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.product-quick-view a').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        midClick: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade'
    });

});
```

And it works fine but only for elements that is shown on first page. When i scroll down page and infinite scroll add next products to page , the script wont work (to that products).

Comment: probably you should call .magnificPopup() function on the new elements when they are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add this:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
    jQuery('.product-quick-view a').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        midClick: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade'
    });
});
```

The above will be executed whenever a ajax is successfully completed.

Comment: But it will add a second (and third, fourth, ...) handler for the items that were already on the page. Depending on the plugin, that can cause issues.